# Как вывести пустую ячейку в GridView если данные для вывода отсутствуют?

Tags: yii2, gridview

Вывожу в GridView Yii2 данные типа FLOAT то есть числа.
И там где **0 или данные отсутствуют** выводится **0**, по этому не понятно где 0 а где пусто...

Как выводить при 0 -> 0, а при отсутствии данных пустую ячейку?

Comment: покажи полностью код, на словах не ясно

Answer (score 0):

Если *>PHP7.0*, то через тернарник:

```
[
        ...
        'value' => function($model) {
            return !is_null($model->myFloat) ? $model->myFloat : '';
        }
],
```

в ином случае можно через null coalesce operator

```
[
        ...
        'value' => function($model) {
            return $model->myFloat ?? '';
        }
],
```